# Why aren't residuals in Poisson regression on the scale of the response variable?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, residuals, poisson-regression

I am running models in R using an OLS as well as using a GLM with a Poisson distribution and  log link function.

```
df <- data.frame(x1=runif(100), x2=runif(100))

df$ols_y <- rnorm(100)
df$glm_y <- rpois(100, lambda=5)


ols_mod <- lm(ols_y ~ x1 + x2, data=df)
glm_mod <- glm(glm_y ~ x1 + x2, data=df, family=poisson)
```

Now, I can recover the original y values if I use the ols model to predict the training data and add back the residual (rounding to avoid floating-point issues).  I can also use `fitted.values` instead of re-running the model on the training data:

```
all(round(ols_mod$fitted.values + ols_mod$residuals, 5) == round(df$ols_y, 5))
> TRUE
all(round(predict(ols_mod, df) + ols_mod$residuals, 5) == round(df$ols_y, 5))
> TRUE
```

But if I do it with my Poisson model, even using `type="response"`, the values don't match.

```
all(round(predict(glm_mod, df, type="response") + glm_mod$residuals, 5) == round(df$glm_y, 5))
> FALSE
all(round(glm_mod$fitted.values + glm_mod$residuals, 5) == round(df$glm_y, 5))
> FALSE
```

Assuming this was due to the log-link, I also tried to exponentiate the residuals to get them on the scale of the linear predictor, but this also fails.

```
all(round(predict(glm_mod, df, type="response") + exp(glm_mod$residuals), 5) == round(df$glm_y, 5))
```

What am I missing here?  Why aren't the residuals on the scale of the response variable?  Why isn't $\hat{y}_i + r_i = y_i$ ?

Comment: Take a look at the help page at ?residuals.glm. What you are looking at are deviance residuals

Comment: @Knarpie, the `glm$residuals` object contains *working* residuals. It's still correct that you need `residuals(glm_mod, type="response")`.

Comment: Mathematical error: exponentiation couldn't possibly retrieve negative residuals, regardless of what you feed it.

Comment: What happens if you exponentiate the absolute value, somehow keeping track of which were negative?